# How to sort a QListView using a QSortFilterProxyModel?

Tags: sorting, qt4, pyqt4

From the documentation of QSortFilterProxyModel, the view should call "setSortingEnabled" to allow the user to sort the data and/or call sortByColumn.

I would like to use a filter to sort a non-sorted model data which is displayed by a QListView. Is there any way to achieve this?

Note: I am using PyQt4 but this should be a language agnostic problem.

Comment: What does your model look like ? How is it implemented ?

Comment: This is a QStringListModel I would like to sort using a QSortFilterProxyModel.

Comment: It would help to see some code. "sort a non-sorted model data" is not really self explanatory. What's your exact problem with `QSortFilterProxyModel` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, there is no way to make QListView sorted using a QSortFilterProxyModel. I handle it by sorting the data in the (source) model directly.